# vLookup from highlighted cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have some highlighted cells in columns, I want to open  new workbooks according to these cells value . I can do this, but ı want to specify place of these cells value in the new workbooks. (i.e cells(2,6) ). I can succeed in finding cells, I will use vlookup . I know it is too complicated but I have to solve it . 
 I used find method ;

```
   Dim rFound As Range
                             With Sheets("Sheet1")
                          Set rFound = .Cells.Find(What:=ResimNo)
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim GCell As Range

                       Set GCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(ResimNo)




                    'Vlookup

                                With twb.Sheets("Sheet1")
                                 GCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
                                GCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.vLookup(ResimNo, tbl.Range, 2, False)
                                GCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Application.vLookup(.Cells(p, 2), tbl.Range, 4, False)
                                GCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.vLookup(.Cells(p, 2), tbl.Range, 5, False)


                                                    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
                                End With
```